# Command line interface for Lauterbach

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am using Lauterbach debugger (TRACE32 interface) on a 7447 processor. I need to load multiple files onto this processor which I do by running commands in the T32 GUI. Idea is to have a script do the job. One way is to call individual .cmm files in the startup.cmm. But this encounters a problem each time the GUI pops-up a dialog box which again requires a manual input. Can anyone tell me how to use command line interface on T32 to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

A target program is normally loaded to your CPU's memory with the command

```
Data.LOAD.Elf myprog.elf
```

However TRACE32 deletes the symbol data base every time you use Data.LOAD.Elf before loading your new target program. To suppress that use option "/NoClear".

So if you want to load more than one ELF (target program) to your CPU's memory you should do it like this:

```
Data.LOAD.Elf myprog1.elf
Data.LOAD.Elf myprog2.elf /NoClear
Data.LOAD.Elf myprog3.elf /NoClear
```

If you use the Data.LOAD commands in one *.cmm script file or in several *.cmm script  files is up to you, but I would put it one cript.
A dialog box should not pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still needs an answer. 
My script to load elf file:

**flash-elf.cmm:**

```
local &fileName
entry &fileName

print "LOAD &fileName"

IF (!FILE.EXIST(&fileName))
(
    PRINT "No elf file was flashed"
    ENDDO
    // T32 will stay opened
)

DO ~~/demo/powerpc/flash/mpc574xg.cmm "PREPAREONLY" // you should choose your cpu script

FLASH.ReProgram ALL
Data.LOAD.Elf &fileName
FLASH.ReProgram off

SYStem.ResetTarget

GO

QUIT
```

save it either in you home directory (or bin, or any directory that PATH points to) or even next to t32.config (where T32 installed, that's what I use)

now from CMD I call

```
t32mppc.exe -s ~~/flash-elf.cmm  my.elf
```

Here's an answer on how to control T32 via TCP/UDP
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400777/4875690

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and finally, I have figured out that the **popup dialog box** has been created from the **PRACTICE Script (.cmm)**.

So just check out your PRACTICE Script (.cmm) and remove the code that is creating the popup dialog box.

The below code is an example for the code that creates Yes/No dialog box from a PRACTICE Script (.cmm)

```
LOCAL &result
DIALOG.YESNO "Program FLASH memory?"
ENTRY &result
IF &result==FALSE()
 ENDDO
PRINT "User clicked Yes."
```

The above example is from here (https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/ide_ref.pdf).

For controlling trace32 via the command line, please check out this ([controlling trace32 via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883140/controlling-trace32-via-command-line)).